# Tikz-cd is not working after upgrading TeX Live to 2016

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I've just upgraded TeX Live to 2016 to be able to use the `fontawesome` package. I used [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2016). The problem now is that `tikz-cd` is not working anymore. However, `tikz` works.

**Minimal example:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

Hi

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/handlers/first char syntax' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
! I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second line would indicate that you're still on `pgf` 2.x, as the `arrows.meta` library was introduced in version 3. Your example works in TL2016 installed from TUG.org.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Precisely, `pgf` 2.10; and `tikz-cd` v0.9e. So what should I do? Uninstall the one I've just installed and get the one from TUG.org? Just add that `tikz-cd` worked in my previous TeX Live 2013.

Comment: As I said in the comment on your other question, that's what I usually do. But if that PPA really has TL2016 then it should also have `pgf` 3, so you could complain to the maintainer of the PPA.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you very much. I will do it right now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by having incompatible versions of `tikz-cd` and `tikz`, solved by upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

It was only necessary to unistall the PPA version and install the one from TUG.org, as @TorbjørnT. said. Thanks a lot!